# Tor Browser (Alpha) - Android - Separate APK Required

Tags: orbot, android

How to get a separate Tor Browser (Alpha) from the latest release. Since the developers decided to merge the Orbot and Tor Browser aka OrFox together, now it's impossible to separate the two.

Is there a way to get only TorBrowser Alpha APK from this combined package?

Why developers decided to merge the two is beyond my scope of understanding!